# Is it possible to retrieve an uri chunk on AppEngine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, uri

Let's say  i go to `myblog.com/post/12`. The `/post` handler is already defined, but how can i get the parameter being passed? `12`  in this case is the `post_id`.
I'm using the Python SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

Example rule:

```
('/post/(\d+)', views.PostHandler)
```

Example view:

```
class PostHandler(BaseHandler):
    ''' Handler for viewing blog posts. '''
    def get(self, id):
        blog_post = models.BlogPost.get_by_id(int(id))
```